# How can I sort an email alphabetically in bash

Tags: bash, sorting

I am trying to sort a list of emails in alphabetical order in bash to no avail

The emails involve numbers and periods:

```
kori.flap10@flap.com
flap39@flap.com
flap.flap@flap.com
flap@flap.com
k.slick20@flap.uk
```

On using the basic sort command:

`cat text.txt | sort`

it does not sort it alphabetically but instead outputs:

```
flap39@flap.com
flap@flap.com
flap.flap@flap.com
kori.flap10@flap.com
k.slick20@flap.uk
```

How can I sort this to also consider the periods and numbers within the email addresses?

Comment: The sorting of symbols depends on the sorting algorithm. What order did you expect?

Comment: `sort` respects [`LC_COLLATE`](https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Locale-Categories.html). `LC_COLLATE=C sort` or `LC_ALL=C sort` will sort differently. What order do you need? You said "alphabetical order" but `@` or `.` are not in the alphabet, so it's still not clear what you expect.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following `sort` command:

```
$ sort -t @ -k1,1 text.txt
```

With following output:

```
flap@flap.com
flap39@flap.com
flap.flap@flap.com
kori.flap10@flap.com
k.slick20@flap.uk
```

`-t @` splits each e-mail into local name and domain by '@', `-k1,1` sorts on the local name